# Using Room Database, How to I update new data after the app is launched?

Tags: android, android-room, store, playback

I am using Room database. After I launch my pre-populated app to play store how do I update the data for all devices without them having to update the app? The users will not be the ones adding the data...that will be me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to have the source in a central location, perhaps on a server which is checked by the App (perhaps whenever the App is run, perhaps whenever navigating to the Activity or Fragment, perhaps on demand). The central source data could then be refreshed/re-loaded from the centralised location

Perhaps consider [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as the source.